# Error establishing a database connection online server

Tags: php, web-hosting

i have hosted my site but when i click my domain this message appears..

> "Error establishing a database connection"

i want to know what i have to code my config file for a server.
same as localhost?

```
define('DB_NAME', 'b15951672');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you as it helps me every time on my server.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

define('DB_NAME', 'cpanelUserName_databaseName');

define('DB_USER', 'cpanelUserName_databaseUserName');//Create a user for this database in your server and assign this user for your previously created database.

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'databasePasswordForDBUser'); // This is the password created for "cpanelUserName_databaseUserName"
```